# How to setup a Bootstrap 4 form to have a checkbox before the input box?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to achieve this:
[image]

I want to have 4 equally sized colums within one row that contain the label in the first line, and a checkbox in front of the actual input box on the second line.

I tried the following, but could only manage to display one control set in one row, and the margins are broken:

```
<fieldset class="border p-2">
    <legend class="w-auto pl-1 pr-1">Trial Restrictions</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-row">
            <label for="TrialRestrictionExpirationDaysValue">Expiration Days</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check-inline">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1">
            <input type="number" min="0" max="3650" class="form-control" id="TrialRestrictionExpirationDaysValue" name="TrialRestrictionExpirationDaysValue" />
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

How to setup a Bootstrap 4 form to have a checkbox before the input box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using this:

```html
<div class="container">
    <fieldset class="border p-4">
        <legend class="w-auto pl-1 pr-1">Trial Restrictions</legend>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 ">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <label for="TrialRestrictionExpirationDaysValue1">Expiration Days</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check-inline">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1">
                        <input type="number" min="0" max="3650" class="form-control" id="TrialRestrictionExpirationDaysValue1" name="TrialRestrictionExpirationDaysValue" />
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 ">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <label for="TrialRestrictionExpirationDaysValue2">Expiration Days</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check-inline">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox2" value="option1">
                        <input type="number" min="0" max="3650" class="form-control" id="TrialRestrictionExpirationDaysValue2" name="TrialRestrictionExpirationDaysValue" />
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 ">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <label for="TrialRestrictionExpirationDaysValue3">Expiration Days</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check-inline">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox3" value="option1">
                        <input type="number" min="0" max="3650" class="form-control" id="TrialRestrictionExpirationDaysValue3" name="TrialRestrictionExpirationDaysValue" />
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 ">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <label for="TrialRestrictionExpirationDaysValue4">Expiration Days</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check-inline">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox4" value="option1">
                        <input type="number" min="0" max="3650" class="form-control" id="TrialRestrictionExpirationDaysValue4" name="TrialRestrictionExpirationDaysValue" />
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```